# mysql support in php 7

Tags: php, mysql

I have a huge product which was developed on php5.5, so the queries were written using mysql.

As PHP 7 & > has removed the support of mysql, now I am forced to use mysqli instead, but this will consume too much time for me.

Is there any temporary solution to make mysql queries work with PHP 7 for a while? As I am planing to migrate to mysqli but for mean while I need to make the code work with PHP 7 + mysql.

Comment: Downgrade to 5.6 while updating your queries to mysqli or PDO?

Comment: I cannot downgrade to 5.6, since 5.6 is really bad in the performance, 5.6 has had a lot of performance issues.

Comment: But that is your only(my opinion) choice at the moment since you're using MySQL. We are also in the middle of an upgrade to PHP7 but until everything is working we're still stuck with PHP5.6

Comment: It seems like you can still install MySQL [check here](https://ckon.wordpress.com/2015/08/06/put-mysql-functions-back-into-php-7/)

Comment: Can you use PHP 5.5 in the mean time and just use PHP 7 when you've  done migrating your code?

Comment: @Cedric I tried PHP 5.5 as well, but PHP 5.5 has a bug with json encoding, it use to create a json of integer values and all data types into strings, I mean I would get all the strings even for floats and integers.

Comment: The best course of action is to use a shim/polyfill - [check this library out](https://github.com/dshafik/php7-mysql-shim)

Answer (score 3):

You could recreate the mysql functions and use mysqli in these. This is not really clean, but it will work and is a fast solution until you can refactor your application

For example:

```
function mysql_connect($host, $username, $password, $db) {
    return mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);
}

function mysql_query($query){
    return $mysqli_query($query);
}
```

Comment: That's the correct answer. Beside that fact nobody should do that in production. All answers and comments with "5.6 is no option" are simply wrong. It should not be done this way, but its an possible option.

Comment: Yes something this like crossed my mind as well, but how can I make these functions available across all the website? where should I put these functions?

Comment: If i'm not mistaking there isn't an autoloading system for function as there is for classes, you will need to `require` a file that contain those function everywhere your code needs it

Comment: @syscall That was me being to fast and not testing it, changed it :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but, please test your code : `$mysqli_query()`? What is `$` here? And [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/mysqli_query) requires `$link` as first argument.