# Errors that can be caught in PHP

Tags: php

Version PHP 7+

Please, look at my questions carefully. I know about php7_mysql's questions. That is NOT my question.

```
first:
$i = 0;
try {
    if ( $i == 0 )
        $link = mysqli_connect("1.1.1.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
    else
        echo 'Another link.';

} 
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    $i = 1;
    goto first;
}

// Continue execution
echo 'repair complete!';
```

This error can be caught.

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002):
repair complete!
```

BUT, if it looks like this

```
first:
$i = 0;
try {
    if ( $i == 0 )
        $link = mysql_connect("1.1.1.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
    else
        echo 'Another link.';

} 
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    $i = 1;
    goto first;
}

// Continue execution
echo 'repair complete!';
```

This error cannot be caught.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in D:\wamp64\www\test.php:409 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\wamp64\www\test.php on line 409
```

So, I wonder what types of errors can be caught. Then I can do something about it. Let the script continue.

Comment: PHP7 removed `mysql_*` which can been seen on the documentation. If you want to use it, install it and include in in `php.ini`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql support in php 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50057193/mysql-support-in-php-7)

Comment: The clue is in the text. The first is a _warning_, the second is a _fatal error_. Warnings are not caught. Fatal errors are not exceptions (you're catching Exception).

Comment: oh,oh.I see . BUT ,Pls look at my question carefully.

Comment: You can catch anything can throws an `Exception`, or anything that extends such. You can disable warnings in `php.ini` again or by code in error reporting.

Comment: EDIT: you can catch a fatal error. Just catch \Error instead of \Exception

Comment: [What-are-the-different-types-of-errors-in-PHP](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-different-types-of-errors-in-PHP) Does that help?

Comment: In deed most poeple seem not to understand your question, this may be a result of the question beeing at the very end. Please take a looke at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It might help to write your question first and show the examples later. (Or skip the examples in this specifc question at all. They divert the attention...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Throwable hierarchy in PHP7:

https://www.php.net/manual/ro/language.errors.php7.php

You need to catch \Error or \Throwable, more generally, or a specific error. \Exception is not an \Error and PHP (not mysql) is throwing \Error because the function name you're trying to use does not exist. If mysql was there it would indeed be throwing \Exception's, but it's not, mysql_ functions were removed. You need to use the mysqli or PDO extension in PHP 7.

If you are trying to run different codes for different PHP versions, the correct approach is to use `function_exists(<function_name>)`, `class_exists` etc, not to try to run the code anyway and catch an error that should really not be triggered in the first place in decent code.

To sum up: your problem IS mysql, you are wrongly assuming that the error is thrown by an extension which in reality does not exist anymore, while it's actually thrown by PHP trying to tell you just that and you should not catch it.